# Медленная работа MySQL на Homestead

Tags: mysql, vagrant, homestead

Проблема следующая: очень медленно работает MySQL на Homestead. Команда `top` показывала 30% потребления памяти, после чего было увеличено значение memory в Homestead.yaml с 2048 до 4096 и процент упал до каких-то 15. Тем не менее ответа приходится ждать 10-15 секунд, что очень расстраивает. Использую iMac с Yosemite. Homestead, а заодно Vagrant с VirtualBox, переустанавливал не раз, проблему это не решает.

Какие действия можно предпринять для улучшения ситуации?

**UPDATE:**

Проблема ярко выражена на странице результатов поиска на сайте. Статические и "почти" статические страницы тоже не радуют (средняя скорость загрузки - 1-2с), но именно на странице поиска все особо печально. Попробовал отключить сфинкс - скорость выросла на ~4-5с, включил поддержку NFS - почти никак не сказалось на скорости. После этого в настройках Homestead.yaml я вернул значение memory 2048 и... это никак не повлияло на скорость загрузки страницы! Тех 30 секунд, которые я называл выше уже нет. Сейчас скорость колеблется в пределах 6-12с в зависимости от количества поисковых результатов (поиск работает и без сфинкса). Судя по всему проблема была в сфинксе, но решилась она не полностью. Хочу заметить, что проблема наблюдается именно на моей машине, на VPS-хостинге все в порядке и страница отдается быстро.

Comment: Какой диск стоит в компьютере, сколько свободного места, сколько реально свободной оперативы (не залезает ли оно в своп)?

Comment: Короче. Если оно работает медленно, то практически ничего без серьезного нажима сделать нельзя. Мои подозрения - на большое количество дисковых операций, возможно, оперативка вашей машины на самом деле располагается в свопе основной, хост-машины. Внутри вируталки вы можете установить программу iotop, чтобы посмотреть, что происходит с дисковыми операциями внутри виртуалки. Хорошим плюсом будет включить профайлинг в фреймворке - возможно, у вас почему-то сеть тупит по десять секунд, а на самом деле все летает. Но вообще это _очень_ обширная тема для дебага.

Comment: @Etki, спасибо за ответ. Так как проблема наблюдается на работе, то дать ответ с какими-то цифрами смогу только завтра. Сейчас могу сказать следующее: коллеги используют Macbook Pro с Mavericks и у них такой проблемы нет, а так как мы используем одну и ту же сеть, то проблему с ней можно исключить. Так же замечаю, что мой iMac сам по себе работает не достаточно шустро. Свободного места на диске думаю достаточно, так как установлено на нем только самое необходимое: IDE, Vagrant, браузеры и еще парочка небольших утилит.

Comment: "а так как мы используем одну и ту же сеть" - я вообще про localhost <-> VM; "Свободного места на диске думаю достаточно" - проблема не в свободном месте на диске, проблема в количестве свободной оперативной памяти.

Comment: @Etki, прошу прощение за продолжительное отсутствие, совсем не было времени заняться проблемой. Итак, что имеем: HDD - Serial ATA 7200 об/мин объёмом 500 ГБ. Мониторинг системы - http://storage3.static.itmages.ru/i/15/0420/h_1429515237_6720713_054d3524b1.png , iotop - http://storage2.static.itmages.ru/i/15/0420/h_1429515759_6726712_9d35f10177.png

Comment: А так же htop - http://storage4.static.itmages.ru/i/15/0420/h_1429516549_9421326_8109a580cb.png

Comment: Внес немного уточнений в тему.

Comment: Судя по тому, что я вижу, mysql вообще простаивает, в то же время gulp жрет все подряд. Судя по iotop, нагрузка на диск вообще нулевая. Это было снято в момент выполнения запроса? Если попробовать xdebug'ом или внутренними средствами laravel снять снапшот профилирования, у него общее время будет равняться реальному времени запроса? За сколько отработает пустой hello-world контроллер без обращений к mysql?

Comment: Gulp жрет много, согласен, но даже когда он не запущен, проблема остается. "Это было снято в момент выполнения запроса?" - нет, сейчас попробовал посмотреть с запросом - все по нулям, лишь под конец запроса секундный скачек - http://storage4.static.itmages.ru/i/15/0420/h_1429535645_3760554_331f84e8e5.png  "За сколько отработает пустой hello-world контроллер без обращений к mysql?" - 100-200ms. С профайлером сейчас траблы, не могу им проверить. Еще хотел уточнить, что текущая задержка сейчас наблюдается у всех коллег на работе, причем чем меньше БД, тем меньше задержка (БД маленькие: 20-50Мб).

Comment: Может быть, дело в каком-нибудь сложном вопросе и отсутствии индексов? Там может быть какой-нибудь миддлвейр, который автоматом при каждоме http-запросе гоняет этот sql-запрос? Профайлинг сделать довольно легко, достаточно поставить и включить xdebug, поставить хром-хелпер, выбрать там "trace" и совершить запрос, после этого выудить файл .out из /tmp.

Comment: Тогда почему далеко не на самом мощном VPS все работает достаточно быстро? "после этого выудить файл .out из /tmp" - не могу найти, где именно он должен находиться, в корне проекта?

Comment: Не могу сказать, потому что не знаю точного сетапа, может, там в целом кэши / сервак настроен, может, это следствие влияния виртуалки на мускул, а на vps не виртуалбокс, а что-то другое. Файл должен лежать в `/tmp` и называться что-нибудь типа `1232131231.out.stacktrace` или как-то так (сейчас маску уже и не вспомню, `ls tmp | grep out` должен найти). После нахождения его можно просто скормить PHPStorm.

Comment: Сделал профайлинг, но там куча вызовов - куда смотреть, на что обращать внимание? Учитывая то, что проект, над которым идет работа, не маленький, может ли быть такое, что vagrant на маке тупо не тянет его, из-за чего и происходят такие задержки?

Comment: Судя по всему в этом и заключалась проблема. Поиск на сайте осуществляется по туристическим предложениям, сейчас удалил 4000, осталось около 1500, результат - страница загружается за ~2c.

Comment: "куда смотреть, на что обращать внимание" - там можно отсортировать по времени выполнения, там будет занимающий 100% фронт-контроллер, а внутри него вещи поинтереснее; "Поиск на сайте осуществляется по туристическим предложениям, сейчас удалил 4000, осталось около 1500" - надо делать анализ запросов. "может ли быть такое, что vagrant на маке тупо не тянет его" - вагрант может быть только медленнее в целом, ресурсов вые му выделили достаточно.